# How to make permanent changes to iptables of CentOS 5.5

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy, centos5, csf

I want to make an iptable rule permanent so if the server is rebooted I won't have to add the rule again.

Specifically a rule I have related to nginx being reverse proxy of apache.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s ! 266.266.266.266 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 85`

I tried `iptables-save` but either I didn't use the correct files or it doesn't work for me.

Note that I use directadmin control panel for the server as well as http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html

So there is a possibility those interfere, since the rules were not there even though there wasn't any server reboot several times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `service iptables save` command.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `/etc/init.d/iptables save`.

This will write out the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.  Look at that file to verify that the contents has the rules that you want (it won't be in same format as `iptables` run from the command line, but you should be able to get the gist of it).

Make sure that iptables is set to run on reboot.  Run `chkconfig --list iptables` to see if it's "on" for startup.  If not, run `chkconfig iptables on`, and the run `chkconfig --list iptables`.  You should see "on" in runlevels 2, 3, 4, 5.